# nested data driven template

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have nested adress component and I want reuse it in my outer form, it works fine but problem is when I want duplicate addresse ( add() button)

You can check this plunker, https://plnkr.co/edit/b0NQcgY1Vk0aKNITxC8A?p=preview my push() seems not working and I don't understand why, can someone help here updating this plunker

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      title: [''],
      address: this.fb.array([])
    });
  }

  add(){

    this.form.get('address').push(this.fb.control(this.adress.form))
  }
```

and template is

```
<address-control *ngFor="let control of form.get('address').controls; let i = index" formGroupName="{{i}}"></address-control>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be because of `this.adress.form` it should be: `this.form.adress`.

Try this:

```
add(){
  this.form.get('address').push(this.fb.control(this.form.adress))
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: nop this not help you can check update here https://plnkr.co/edit/U5RALchHfEL0r1Jck8Yb?p=preview but I don't understand why this.form.adress if I want form from my ViewChild this.adress.form ... you can fork my plunker and let me know what you mean

Answer (score 0):

I believe what's called for here is to track the `*ngFor` with a dummy track by function to prevent it from reinitializing our components any time a change is made, combined with a `setControl` when initializing the address component and an additional input so we can set the right control:

**main.component.html**

```
 <div formArrayName="addresses">
    <address-control [formArrayInput]="form.controls['addresses']" [index]="i"
      *ngFor="let address of form.controls['addresses'].controls; let i = index;trackBy:trackByFn"></address-control>
  </div>
```

**main.component.ts** we're going to push a dummy group to be overwritten by the address component:

```
add(){
   this.form.controls['addresses'].push(this.fb.group({}));
}

trackByFn(index, item) {
   return 0;
}
```

**address-control.component.ts**

```
@Input() formArrayInput;
@Input() index;
form;

ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.formArrayInput);
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    street: '',
    city: ''
    zip: ''
  });
  this.formArrayInput.setControl(this.index, this.form);
}
```

Here's a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/IANa0TLAsPAxaEN1379v?p=preview) forked from yours.